# How to add EmptyFolder or directory in a zip file using ZipOutputStream

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

I want to be able creating zip files that contain empty folders, using  `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream`. I can use `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip.CreateEmptyDirectories = true`, but FastZip doesn't allow UTF8 file names.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I came across the same issue (zipping empty directories with ZipOutputStream).

I am making a recursive call based on different parent directories.

```
public void CompressFolder(string path, ZipOutputStream zipStream, int folderOffset)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        //this is where I add the empty directory
        //code begin
        if (files.Count() == 0 && directories.Count() == 0)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            string cleanName = ZipEntry.CleanName(path.Substring(folderOffset)) + "/";
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(cleanName);
            zipEntry.DateTime = di.LastWriteTime;
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
            return;
        }
        //code end

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            string cleanName = ZipEntry.CleanName(file.Substring(folderOffset));
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(cleanName);
            zipEntry.DateTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
            zipEntry.Size = fileInfo.Length;
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
            byte[] numArray = new byte[4096];
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                StreamUtils.Copy(fileStream, zipStream, numArray);
            }
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            CompressFolder(directory, zipStream, folderOffset);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/10856/29901.aspx where (I quote):
"Our current roadmap includes UTF entry filename handling [...]"
Which would lead me to understand that UTF filenames are not currently supported.

Comment: Thanx, I kno that using  ZipOutputStream we can zip files with UTF8 name, but the question is how I can allow to zip empty folders too??